# Upload file depending on date

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm quite new to PHP and I have a script to upload files into a specific folder. I would like to know if there is a way of uploading the files into a folder identified by the date of the day when the file is uploaded.

Here is the code, which I know is very basic:

```
<?php

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
 echo "El fichero ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])." ha sido enviado";
} else{
 echo "Hubo un error, inténtalo de nuevo!";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
```

can be changed to add date to it

```
$target_path = $target_path  .date("Y-m-d") ."/" .basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
```

This should make it something like

> yourpath/dir/2012-09-09/filename.txt

Comment: Hi Hanky thanks for the help, but it does not create the directory either it uploads the file nowhere. Do I need to do anything else like adding rights?

Comment: Yes you first have to create that directory. You can create using `mkdir($target_path.date("Y-m-d"));`